# Count Session in Nhibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I am using Fluent NHibernate. I want to count number of session gets created and present in application. Is there any way to count that ?

Please share your view and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your configuration, do also:

```
var config = new Configuration();

config.DataBaseIntegration(db => { .. });
config.SessionFactory().GenerateStatistics();
```

And then look at:

```
SessionFactory.Statistics.EntityFetchCount
```

Comment: Thank you alex for response, I do not get GenerateStatistics Method but get some information related Statistics. which is new for me. I have enabled in config by <property name="generate_statistics">true</property> and get statistics by NHibernateConfiguration.SessionFactory.Statistics.ConnectCount; thank you so much you have saved my lot of time.

Comment: no problem. you are welcome. you are missing the `using NHibernate.Cfg;` - that is why you don't see the GenStatistics method.